# Null value for generic class

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a class like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class MyList<T> : List<T>
    {
        public int SelectedIndex { get; set; }

        public T CurrentItem
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.SelectedIndex > this.Count)
                    return null;

                return this[this.SelectedIndex];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am creating a class that derive from list and create a property for getting the current item.

If `SelectedIndex` is a wrong value, I am returning `null` but it has an error

> Cannot convert null to type parameter 'T' because it could be a
>   non-nullable value type. Consider using 'default(T)' instead.

I want the return value to be `null` not `default(T)`.

what should I do?

Comment: If you want it to be able to return `null` then you would either need to make it a nullable type, or place a constraint on T to make it a reference type by using `T : class`.

Comment: What will be T in your case ?

Comment: What do you think `default(T)` is? For reference-types this evaluates to `null`. For value-types (e.g. `int`) this is either zero or whatever the types default-type is.

Comment: Might-be-interesting-to-read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt/21694054#21694054

Comment: As an alternative, you can consider throwing an `IndexOutOfRangeException` instead of returning null. Well, that would already occur if you just `return this[this.SelectedIndex]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`null` is an invalid value for value types such as `int` or `double`. Therefore, you have to restrict the generic type parameter to classes like so:

```
public class MyList<T> : List<T> where T : class
```

Then, the compiler error will disappear.